# How to get continuous data to be treated as discrete?

Tags: r

I have data on five questions over ten weeks as answered by 150 students. I inputted the data using the student's student #, but now their student numbers are being treated as continuous variables.

```
 Student   Question Type timePeriod week Rating
1  789331        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      4
2  805933        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      5
3  826523        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      4
4  832929        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      4
5  838607        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      5
6  841903        Q1  SNR        Rt1    1      2
```

I would like the student numbers to be treated as discrete variables, so I can use them as legend labels when graphing more than one students' response to questions. 
Is there an easy way to tell R to treat all the numbers in the 'Student' column as labels rather than data?

[What my graph currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsOhT.png)

Comment: Convert them to character or factor (`as.character()`, `as.factor()` for example).

Comment: @joran
Hi! Thanks for your response.
I'm not exactly sure how to do that... I'm a complete R newbie. Any tips on how to actually write it would help!

Comment: Lots of different ways. It looks like you're using **ggplot2**, so one option would be to write `factor(Student)` rather than `Student` in your ggplot code. Or you could create a new column like `data$StudentFactor <- as.factor(data$Student)` and then use that column instead.